# closure of integral scheme is again integral scheme

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra

Let $X$ be a noetherian scheme , such that $Z$ is a closed subscheme that does not contain an irreducible component of $X$. Therefore we have a dense open subset $U = X \setminus Z$, assume we have a integral scheme $C_U\subset U$ if we take closure in $X$ it will still be an integral scheme of $X$.

---

My attempt being integral is the same as being irreducible and reduced, clear that closure of irreducible space is irreducible, however it's not very clear why the closure of reduced scheme is reduced?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The inclusion $C_U\to X$ is a locally closed immersion, i.e. a closed immersion followed by an open one. I presume what you mean by 'taking the closure in X' (which a priori is only a topological operation) is to take the scheme theoretic image of $C_U$ inside $X$.

Now as $C_U$ is reduced, the scheme theoretic image $Z$ in $X$ is obtained by endowing the topological closure $\overline{C_U}\subseteq X$ with the reduced induced closed subscheme structure. This is essentially due to [this Lemma](https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/0356), which shows that $C_U\to X$ indeed factors through $Z\to X$, and that if it factors through any other closed subscheme $Z'\to X$, we must have $Z\subseteq Z'$, and thus, as $Z$ is reduced, also a closed immersion $Z\to Z'$.

In particular, we obtain that the scheme theoretic image $Z$ of $C_U$ in $X$ is reduced.

Comment: Very thanks imtrying46 , it makes this question very clear.